# How to check if an element has been removed from a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

How can I check that an element has been properly removed from a `Map` in java?

Given:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,Object> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
myMap.put(1, new Object());

myMap.remove(1);
```

Is the below code the only way to check it?

```
myMap.contains(1);
```

Comment: what else would you want? What is it that you don't like about `myMap.contains(1);` to check if `1` is or is not an element of `myMap`?

Comment: [`Map::remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) returns the element that was removed if the key passed as the argument was present. Otherwise if it was not present it returns `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) returns the removed object, or `null` if it is not present in the map:

> **Returns:**
>   the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

```
Object removedObject = myMap.remove(1);
boolean wasRemoved = removedObject != null;
```

---

In fact by using, `contains()`, the object might have been removed by another thread between the calls to `remove()` and `contains()`, if the map is shared between threads. That your question uses a `ConcurrentHashMap` hints that concurrency might be a case here.